# CSS issues in IE and Mozilla 

Tags: php, html, css, firefox

I have a site,whwn I view it from Chrome,it is ok but when I see it from IE the footer doesn't look good .Moreover In Mozilla it is fully distorted.Can anyone tell me what could be the CSS issues?Do I have to make different CSS files for each browser?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have a floating element ncenter which is 190px wide and then try to stuff a 680px wide div into it and it continues on. You don't need browser specific css, you need to sort your layout. If you don't have the firebug extension for firefox, go get it and inspect your page.

Comment: Why it is showing ok in chrome then?

Comment: It probably treats the overflow differently (because that's what it is). That's a question to ask google though. Firefox is behaving correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would create a main CSS file for structure and css that works on all browsers, and then as you notice differences between browsers or you know of differences in rendering in browsers you can load browser specific css to rememdy the differences. One way is to use html conditionals when loading css such as

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

php should have some browser detection plugins or libraries you can use to make this easier than typing each one out.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html has more examples of the types of versioning and browsers you can detect

Answer (score 0):

Add different CSS files for each browser,webkite.-moz and IE will be three different CSS

Answer (score 0):

You Need to check Cross-Browser Compatibility [check this link](http://www.noupe.com/tools/the-importance-of-cross-browser-compatibity-tips-and-resources.html)
You can get some help from [this site](http://interactiveblend.com/blog/online/cross-browser-compatibility-with-css3/)